# Problem in login page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created a login page. In this page i used div tag which is mapped with images for good design purposes. i have enabled the forms authentication in web.config.

So finally images i mapped in div is not appearing in the login page.
please help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume the images are not displaying due to access? Where do the images exist?  If they exist in a directory that is locked down to forms authentication, the pictures cannot display.

Try adding a `web.config` file to your images directory and to allow public access to these files.

Here is what the `web.config` should contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="images"> 
        <system.web> 
            <authorization> 
                <allow users="*"/> 
            </authorization> 
        </system.web> 
    </location>
    <system.web>
        <!-- Your normal web.config stuff here -->
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also check your IIS settings for the application in general to make sure you are allowing anonymous access.

**EDIT:** Make sure to move your images to a folder that does not require authorization.  If you have them in the same directory as your secured aspx pages then you won't be able to access them.

**EDIT 2:** Included the info provide by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198643/thomas) and [Sky Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242897/sky-sanders) as it included a better solution.  See comment threads on answers for more information.

Comment: how to add in web.confg file about images directory

Comment: @Sarathi1904 just create a file called `web.config` and copy the xml content I posted above into it.  Then add that file to the directory where your images exist.  Make sure the images are in their own directory and not included with all your aspx files.

Comment: This *may* work for most cases, but the rule you specify is misleading. IMO better form would be to clearly specify unfettered access with allow=* as shown below.

Comment: @Sarathi1904 Although this may work, I think the accepted answer should be from Thomas. I don't think the answer deserved a negative vote though as it does work. Not sure if you can change you accepted answer but I could delete my answer if that would help.

Comment: you can't delete until the check is moved.

Comment: @Sky Sanders Yes noticed that when I tried to delete it.  If the user doesn't reassign the correct answer, I will ammend my answer to include the info provided by Thomas and give credit for the fixes.

Answer (score 4):

If the images are not meant to be protected and should be visible on all pages, then I would add a location tag in the main web.config:

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: @Sarathi - you should probably accept this answer if it is exactly what you want. just sayin....

Comment: +1 I forgot about `location` and it keeps all the configuration in one place.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, another way to achieve the same result is simply to put another web.config into the images folder with an authorization area sans the location.

Answer (score 2):

Add a web.config file to your images directory containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will allow your login page, which is usually viewed by unauthenticated users, to show images.

Comment: The * will only allow all authenticated users to access the directory.  If it's a login page they would not be autheticated yet.

Comment: @Kelsey - sorry dude. you are mistaken. trust me.

Comment: +1 After reading your comment I looked it up and you are correct in the `*` means any user.  So now I am curious as to why you would use `?`... without your comment I would never have looked it up so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Kelsey - Generally you would use '?' in conjunction with a `deny` to exclude unauthenticated users. Specifying `allow` unauthenticated users, if superceded by a `deny` '*', which is a common base for lockdowns, would result in ONLY unauthenticated users being able to access the resource. (in theory. I have not tested this). But the point I was trying to make is that you typically deny '?' and allow '*' or deny '*' and allow role xxxx

Comment: @Kelsey- oops meant  deny '?' OR allow '*'